# Evaluating stochastic integral with exponential function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, monte-carlo

After solving for the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, i'm still stuck with a stochastic integral that I can't solve.

The Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process:

$X_{t} = X_{0} e^{-\theta t}+ \mu(1-e^{-\theta t}) + \sigma e^{-\theta t} \int_{0}^{t} e^{\theta s}dW_{s} $

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this stochastic integral? ($\int_{0}^{t} e^{\theta s}dW_{s} $)

*Note that i'm trying to evaluate this expression for a Monte-Carlo simulation. I have already tried discretizing the integral but I would like to improve my results by using the exact solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is $\theta$ a process or a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to simulate that integral, then nothing is mysterious here.
It's just a normal variable of law $ \mathcal{N}\left( 0, \int_{0}^t e^{2 \theta s}.ds \right)$.
If you want to so look at $(W_s)$ as a stochastic process then you can see easily that $ (U_t ):= \left(  \int_{0}^t e^{ \theta s}.dW_s \right) $ is just a change time Brownian process. To be more precise,
Letting $g(t)=  \int_{0}^t e^{2 \theta s}.ds$.
Roughly speaking, there is a Brownian process $\tilde{W}$ such that:
$(U_t)=\left( \tilde{W}_{g(t)} \right)$